# Prove without induction $2^n \mid (b+\sqrt{b^2-4c})^n + (b-\sqrt{b^2-4c})^n $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Prove $2^n \mid (b+\sqrt{b^2-4c})^n + (b-\sqrt{b^2-4c})^n $ for all $n\ge 1$ and $b,c$ are integers.

---

Is it possible to prove this without induction?

Comment: Here's an observation: you can consider this as being the sum of powers of two conjugate solutions to a quadratic equation.

Comment: Exactly! How do I go about proving it ? $$x^2 - bx + c = 0$$

Comment: What do you consider a non-inductive proof? Since you've got a statement of the form 'for all $n$', it's very likely that induction is going to come in _eventually_ in one form or another...

Comment: Have you tried the binomial theorem?

Comment: I am okay with that.. I have an induction proof already with base cases and proving induction step already. I am just trying to see if it is possible to prove this with out the direct induction...

Comment: @MatthewLeingang The binomial theorem uses induction so I'm not sure it's truly any different logically.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang no, it looks interesting xD let me think a bit $$(x+y)^n + (x-y)^n$$

Comment: hey cameron i am okay with binomial thm or any other proofs that dont use induction directly

Comment: Just a thought.  Not sure if it works.

Comment: @pooja, if you do not start a comment with an at sign before the person's name, they will not be notified and may or may not check back and see your comment.

Comment: It is actually not that strict: it suffices to use the first three letters of a name, also it need not be at the beginning of a comment.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with binomial identities. But perhaps someone else is and this could help. If $n$ is even the result  using a binomial expansion is
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n/2}{2n\choose 2k}(b^2)^{(n-k)}(b^2-4ac)^{k}$$

Comment: You can hide the induction, but it is always there :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the characteristic polynomial of twice the integer matrix

$$\mathbb P = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 b & 1 \\
 -c & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

is $\lambda^2 - 2 b \lambda + 4c$, its roots are

$$b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4c}.$$

The sum of those roots is its trace.  Because $\mathbb P$ has integral coefficients, all coefficients of $\mathbb P^n$ are integral, whence $(2\mathbb P)^n = 2^n \mathbb P^n$ are obviously divisible by $2^n$.  But the trace of $(2 \mathbb P)^n$ is the sum of the $n^\text{th}$ powers of the eigenvalues, QED.

---

As others have noted, an induction *must* be lurking here, if only in the relationship $(2\mathbb P)^n = 2^n \mathbb P ^n$.  But this approach helps make the result *immediately obvious*.

#### Edit

There is a close relationship between this solution and one based on [the two-term recursion mentioned by Jack D'Aurizio](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1079373/1489).  That recursion can be represented by the right multiplication of

$$\mathbb Q = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2b & 1 \\
 -4c & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

on $(a_{n-1}, a_{n-2})$, producing $(a_n, a_{n-1})$. Note that $\mathbb Q$ and $2\mathbb P$ have the same characteristic polynomial.  The principal difference, then, is that $2\mathbb P$ has all even coefficients whereas $\mathbb Q$ does not, making the result for $2\mathbb P$ a little more evident.

Comment: The main induction is actually in the observation that $\Bbb P^n$ has integer entries.

Comment: @Brian You're right; there are many inductions lurking here.  The one you point to comes down to asserting that the integers are closed under addition and multiplication.  I'll accept that as immediately obvious.  The crux of the matter, though, is that scalars commute with matrices, whence $(2\mathbb P)^n = 2^n \mathbb P^n$: that shows where the powers of $2$ come from.

Comment: Fascinating how people's intuitions differ: my intuitive reaction is just the opposite. I see the fact that scalars commute with matrices as more obvious than the fact that an integer matrix has integer powers.

Comment: Note, you've got $\sqrt{b^2-4c^2}$ when the original question asked about $\sqrt{b^2-4c}$.

Comment: @Thank you for noticing that, Thomas.  That is easily fixed by replacing one of the $c$'s by $1$; I will make the change.

Answer (score 4):

The sequence given by:
$$ a_n = \left(b+\sqrt{b^2-4c}\right)^n + \left(b-\sqrt{b^2-4c}\right)^n $$
satisfies the recurrence relation:
$$ a_{n+2} = \color{red}{2}b\cdot a_{n+1} - \color{red}{4}c\cdot a_{n}.$$
Since $\nu_2(a_n)\geq n$ holds for $n=0$ and $n=1$, it holds for every $n$ by the previous relation.

Ok, this is still induction :D

Comment: You can divide $a_n$ by $2^n$ and note that the terms of the recurrence relations are still integers.  This implies that $\frac{a_n}{2^n}$ is an integer for all $n$, which is arguably an induction step but a wholly trivial one...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: nice touch.

Comment: Yes I have the exact same proof. I am only looking for non-induction proof here if it is possible. Thanks you though :)

Answer (score 1):

We want to show$$2^n\vert\left(\left(b+\sqrt{b^2-4c}\right)^n+\left(b-\sqrt{b^2-4c}\right)^n\right).$$
Using $x-y=\frac{x^2-y^2}{x+y}$ indeed we have

$$ 2^n\vert\left(\left(b+\sqrt{b^2-4c}\right)^n+\left(\frac{4c}{b+\sqrt{b^2-4c}}\right)^n\right) \\ 2^n\vert\frac{\left(b+\sqrt{b^2-4c}\right)^{2n}+4^nc^n}{\left(b+\sqrt{b^2-4c}\right)^n} \\ 2^n\vert\frac{\left(2b^2-4c+2b\sqrt{b^2-4c}\right)^n+4^nc^n}{\left(b+\sqrt{b^2-4c}\right)^n}\\2^n\vert\frac{2^n\left(\left(b^2-2c+b\sqrt{b^2-4c}\right)^n+2^nc^n\right)}{\left(b+\sqrt{b^2-4c}\right)^n}.$$

Comment: Don't you still have to show that the remainder after dividing through by $2^n$ is an integer?

Comment: @Cameron Yes, but since now I can't spend longer on that, I hoped the OP would be somewhat satisfied / someone else would do it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be the roots of the quadratic equation $$x^2 - bx + c = 0$$

Then $$x_1 = \frac{b + \sqrt{b^2 - 4c}}{2}$$ $$x_2 = \frac{b - \sqrt{b^2 - 4c}}{2} $$

The above statement is equivalent to $$2^n \,\big| \, 2^n\big({x_1}^n + {x_2}^n \big) $$

Comment: Which helps only if you know that $x_1^n+x_2^n$ is an integer...

Comment: Which can be proven using induction. I realize that's not what the asker wanted, but it works.